# Showing first tab on page load using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have tabs in my asp.net page, On page load I want only first tab to show and hide the second one.

But At the moment i can see all 3 tabs on page load.

I tried hiding second tab in javascript page load function but then I can show it on click it again.

Any help would be appreciated.

here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>

ul.tab {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.tab li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.tab li a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
ul.tab li a:focus, .active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
}
</style>
<body>

<ul class="tab">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this function to your script

```
OnloadOpenCity();

function OnloadOpenCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 1; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 1; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "none";
    evt.currentTarget.className += "none";
}
```

DEMO

[Codepen](http://s.codepen.io/dannibla/debug/GNpoLE)

Answer (score 1):

Use bootstrap tabs..I will hide the remaining tabs

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```